# I have a web form that will not save input when attempting to save the document

Tags: forms, web, save, lotus-domino

1. Domino web page built using a Notes table to layout the fields
2. Some text fields are hidden and HTML Text Area are what is presented to the user
3. The text area HTML appears to be properly built, here is an example:

   `<textarea name = "printDescription" style="height:40px; width:98%;" placeholder="enter description here..."><Computed Value></textarea>`

...the computed text is simply the same as the name..."printDescription"

4. Field properties...HTML tab...id is set to equal the field name
5. The Notes field is hidden for web, visible in client
6. The textarea is hidden in client and visible in web
7. Nothing in onSubmit event of the form
8. $$Return field is computed value with "[url I want it to go to]" as the value...this works fine
9. Two Notes buttons....one with @Command([FileSave]) as client command...visible in both client and web, the other with javascript:  document.forms[0].submit();

I am missing something...the page looks great, but whenever I click either of the buttons, any input I put in the field is not being saved....actually no fields using text area are being saved, while other fields such as radio buttons and plain text fields are being saved.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Check the form properties - propeller hat tab - 'generate html for all field' needs to be checked or the field needs to be hidden by style from the browser. 
 If the field is not visible in the webclient, it wont get posted to the notesdocument

Comment: Generate HTML for all fields was checked...sorry I did not mention that.  A couple of other things....I tried changing the field to be hidden with CSS only,  but that did not help.    No 'saveOptions' field on this form.   I have manager rights to this database (and am logged in).   Form is available to Public Access Users.  Good ideas, but my problem persists.   It will end up being something very simple I am sure.

Comment: another thing...there is no WQS agent for this form, so nothing is clearing fields or anything like that (nothing I built, I should say)

Comment: What data type and field type are the printDescription field?

Comment: Any reason why you use a <textarea> in your source and not the field itself?

Comment: I need the space it provides for data entry, where I can set the height and width and allow the user to even grab the handle on the bottom right of the field (textarea) itself and type paragraphs if necessary.    And I do not want to use rich text fields..just large data input areas for text.

Comment: This issue came up again in another form.   I had abandoned the first form, but I cannot abandon this one.   Answers to the two questions above....data type is text, and using a text area to give user a larger space to enter input.    If there is a better way, say with field properties (HTML tab?) I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to one of the suggestions, I turned OFF the checkbox to generate html for all fields, and it worked.

The way I read this is if I have it turned ON, then the HTML that is generated 'overrides' the input capabilities of a textarea wkth the same name as the field, and turning it OFF lets the field not be considered on the webform and lets the  act as an input item.   I may have that wrong, but that is what I did, and it is working now,